# PutInt in bundle not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I've a problem in bundle ,
I can't send int value if the value is from a text field , I have to pass year to the another fragment but it shows me error and the application is suspended .

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
          // final int value = year ;

            AddTaskFragment frag = new AddTaskFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

            Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
            bundle2.putInt("akey2",year );
            frag.setArguments(bundle2);

            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame, frag);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();


        }
    });
```

And here :

```
 Bundle bundle1 = getArguments();
    if (bundle1 != null){
        strtext2 =  bundle1.getInt("akey2");
        taskdate.setText(strtext2);
        //taskdeadline.setText(strtext2);
    }
```

taskdate is a textfield .

Comment: getting int value in string without type casting?

Comment: strtext2 is int type

Answer (score 3):

Your `TextView` expects a resource of type `String`, convert your `strtext2` `int` value to `String` like that:

```
taskdate.setText(Integer.toString(strtext2));
```

or

```
taskdate.setText(strtext2+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing type casting properly. Try this code

```
String strtext2 = String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("akey2"));
```

For more help. try to add stacktrace please

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
taskdate.setText(String.valueOf(strtext2));
```

You need to typecast "strtext2" into String as TextView considers int parameters to be resource types